# Able to build app onto iPhone but core data for app is missing

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios-provisioning

I just moved my first app to my iPhone for testing (yeah). But when I run the app on the iPhone no data appears in my tableviews. My NSLogs also show 0 rows returning from my ManagedObject query when it runs on my iPhone. However, I always have data appearing in this app when I've run it on the Mac simulator.

Is there something I need to do to also get the core data database over to my iPhone? Is there a way to check to see if the database made it to the iPhone? I don't get any errors when it runs but the data isn't showing up.

Yes, I'm a newbie - appreciate your help.

Comment: Post your relevant CoreData calls (specifically, how do you open your data)

Comment: Do you init your database with some data?

Comment: Yes, I do have seed data in the database for testing. However, it's not showing up. In the app, it creates a profile and that data is saved but it's a newly initialized database.

Comment: Maybe what I have to do is go find that sqlite database on my mac and add my seed data to it? I thought it would just take the same db that I was using with the simulator.  When I drill down in Finder on my Mac Library -> Application Support -> iPhone Simulator -> 4.3 I find the db in which I was putting my seed database. Where do I do that for my iPhone. I think that's the question. I don't have a similar path in Finder, unless it's completely somewhere else.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for unspecific info, but the usual tutorials for DB talk about copying the DB into your project so that it gets copied onto the phone it's being deployed to.  Check those tutorials.

Comment: I realized in writing my responses above that that is probably what is needed. Don't worry about being unspecific, I'm sure I can find them. I just needed to understand what the problem was first :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, copy the sqlite database with the seed data into your bundle by dragging it into Xcode.

Then, in your app delegate where you set up your persistent store, add this to the `persistentStoreCoordinator`method:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
       pathForResource:@"dbname" ofType:@"sqlite"];
   if (defaultStorePath) {
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
        copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:[storeURL path] error:nil];
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Mundi. I have just looked through two books and didn't see it so I appreciate your sharing this!